# SSIS - Local Variables

Tags: ssis

The main goal of my SSIS package is to read sql code, and then execute.The script task is going to read the code in the SQL file, then pass the code into a global variable.
The SQL task executes the code stored in the variable. This works fine, but I'm using one variable to store the sql code. Because of this, I cannot execute 
multiple steps in parallel. Is there a way I can avoid creating multiple variables to store the SQL code? Would local variables work, and if so, how ? 
[image]

Comment: No, if you want them to run concurrently the two SQL scripts need to be stored in different memory.

Comment: How about assigning sql statement to SQL Task by name? I.E. Using "Script" to assign an sql statement to "SQL Task" and "SQL Task 1". In my script, I would specify the sql task by name, and assign it sql statement. I think DTS 2000 has something like this.

Comment: I think you're talking about expressions, which use variables.  So if you want these to run concurrently, you need to store the SQL in different memory.  Why are you so opposed to creating 2 variables instead of 1?

Comment: I am trying to this for 20+ different sql statements, and I want to avoid creating that many variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a package (call it X) just to do one:

```
script -> sql task
```

In X, define some package parameters that you need to pass from caller package to X, if required. For example, table name? and inject that into your dynamic SQL.
Otherwise, define them as variables.

Then create a main package that calls multiple X packages. Then you can run them in parallel.

As child package cannot return value back to main package (if required), you have to devise alternative ways to pass values back to main package. For example, by updating values in a table. The main package waits for X to finish thus the main package can then perform more tasks after.